# Get webBrowser control width & height value

Tags: c#, winforms

trying to get width and height of webBrowser form as variable.

```
var width = webBrowser1.Width;
var height = webBrowser1.Height;
```

save another similar post where the code was:

webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

but could not get that to work.

I've notice there is a property called 'size' in layout properties but wasn't able to get the value

Comment: Have you instantiated WebBrowser1 when you run this line?

Comment: thank you that was the problem the variable was put before the initialize